# Insert and return id no matter the the record exists or not

Tags: sql, postgresql

My requirement is to insert a record into a table if the record doesn't exist, but the SQL needs to return the id no matter the record exists or not. Here is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tags (tag)
                    SELECT 'abc'
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE tag = 'abc') RETURNING tag_id;
```

But it only returns the id if the record doesn't exist, it returns nothing when it has existing records that match the WHERE condition.  Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
  cte_sel(tag_id) as (
    select tag_id from tags where tag = 'abc'),
  cte_ins(tag_id) as (
    insert into tags (tag)
    select 'abc'
    where not exists (select 1 from cte_sel)
    returning tag_id)
select * from cte_sel
union all
select * from cte_ins;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a CTE to get all the records:

```
with to_insert as (
      select 'abc' as tag
     ),
     insert into tags (tag)
         select tag
         from to_insert
         where not exists (select 1 from tags where tags.tag = to_insert.tag)
        )
select *
from to_insert;
```

I would suggest that you `on conflict` instead of `not exists` for preventing duplicates.